# how to select a column not in group by clause without using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm querying an Oracle DB (simplified query. there is more conditions):

```
SELECT        field1, MAX(field2) AS something
FROM          table1
WHERE        (field3 = 'something1')
GROUP BY field1
```

This is a very large database and MAX is killing the query load time.
I don't need the MAX value. Field contains text value. It can be any value as they all should be the same for a given field1. It can be first, last, whatever is faster.

Comment: Why do you think the `max()` is the problem and not the `group by`?

Comment: Gordon took the words out of my mouth - it is much more likely that GROUP BY is the bottleneck. You can test this: SELECT **DISTINCT** field1 from table1 where field3 = 'something1' and see if this takes much less time than the query you posted. If it doesn't, you'll know that the grouping is the problem, not the MAX.

Comment: Because without the max and with group by query is working fine

Comment: Ugly way to remove bad data (duplicates)?

Comment: Not my database. Only able to query it. Cant change the DB structure

Comment: Why would using `DISTINCT` change the db structure?

Comment: Select DISTINCT field1 FROM table1 WHERE (...) is running for over 15 minutes now

Comment: @JacobH - `distinct` forces the rows to be grouped by `field1` (so that a single copy is returned for each group). The same as selecting just `field1` and grouping by it. The OP said that the query *is working fine* without max and **with** group by though, which seems at odds with what he is reporting for `select distinct`. I am not there to see what the OP is actually running, so I will be confused, till the OP clarifies one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to remove "duplicates" from your resultset. Please check:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT field1
  FROM table1
  WHERE field3 = 'something1'
)
SELECT field1, sub.field2
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT field2
             FROM table1 t
             WHERE rownum = 1
               AND t.field1 = c.field1) sub;
```

Indexes on field3 and field1 may speed it up.